# Setting up Windows authentication of an ASP .NET site's ONE route only

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis, active-directory

I wanted to create an alternative two factor authentication option for AD logged in users, and I partially succeeded.

So I have a website with a login view, and an alternative login view for (AD) authenticated users. So the IIS's Windows authentication works just fine:

- On the original page It doesn't want the AD credentials
- On the alternative page (LDAPLogin) it prompts the user for credentials if they're in
  incognito or not logged in the same Domain otherwise it authenticates
  them without the prompt window.

As I mentioned before it is an option for replacing the two factor auth, so for further authentication we won't use windows authentication but the app's own authentication so no connection with the AD in the future until the next login.

However my problem is that every time I send back an unauthorized response (fe. the user's token expires) from my controller to the client no matter where it is from it prompts the user for the credentials. I suspect that this is an automatic operation of the IIS in case of 401 response.
Does anyone have an idea how I can disable the prompting on the pages that are not the alternative login page?

**My web.config for windows auth:**

```
   <system.web>
    <authentication mode="Windows"/>
  </system.web>
  <location path="LDAPLogin">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <deny users="?" />
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>
```

**The authentication prompt:**

[image: the pic]

**IIS settings for Windows auth:**

[image]

Comment: ASP.NET grants access from the configuration file as a matter of precedence. As you set in LDAPLogin, it will reject all unauthorized users, and every time you return from the controller response is unauthorized, so you will be prompted to enter user credentials.

Comment: @BruceZhang You mean I can't prevent the ISS to ask for credentials once windows authentication option is turned on?

Comment: This is the case in the current page. You can store the credentials in the session or token.